# "Upward" curved trajectory from splash of bird catching fish

Tags: water

I captured the photo below of a great egret catching a fish.  Looking at the strand of the water closest to the bird's neck, its trajectory appears to curve **upward**.  In a purely ballistic scenario, I would expect the strand to curve downward.

[image: Great egret striking the water]

What explains the upward curve?  Could it be the result of the bird's head changing its velocity vector after entering the water?

A photographer might ask whether this is an example of "rolling shutter" which is sometimes observed with electronic shutter (where pixels that are read later also record their data later) as compared with a mechanical shutter.  The mechanical shutter was used (1/1000 second) so rolling shutter would not explain this.

By the way, the egret caught the fish.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We only see a still frame, not the fluid motion. We have no info on the velocity field of the strand of water you are referring to. Thus we cannot assume it to be a trajectory like from a fountain, for example.

It might well be:
[image]
This is mostly guesswork on my part. But if the middle of that strand is moving to the left faster than the upper and lower end, this would be an explanation as to how this curvature formed and might still be increasing in the moment we see.

And concerning deeper causes, like the impacting head changing direction, I would say that both the head geometry and the Navier-Stokes equations are too complex to provide a further answer. Somebody please prove me wrong. :)

Nice pictures btw!